# MySQL - Storing multiple fields or one CSV field?

Tags: mysql, csv, product

I have a PRODUCTS table, and need to implement an **availability** system, to be able to filter products by weekday (eg. product is only available on friday).

I'm not sure if I should add an "availability" column with 7 comma separated bool values, each one representing every weekday, or add 7 different columns.

I don't like the CSV method that much, it would also require post-processing to filter the data, but the multiple-columns one seems a bad practice to me. 
I was thinking about that but in a separate table, like PRODUCTS_AVAILABILITY in the format

```
| id | mon | tue | wed | etc...
```

What method should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple fields.

If not you will need to pull the data out into a programming language before doing any processing. You won't be able to index the data.

Go read up on database normalization

Answer (score 0):

You should use many to many table PRODUCTS_AVAILABILITY:

```
product_id | day | availability
```

or json field in one table products (if you use MySQL 5.7+)
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

```
...fields | availability 
            JSON_TYPE('{1:true, 2:false...}');
```